# Macros usage: execute instructions after a backquoted one

Tags: elisp-macros

I have a question about macros.
When I call a macro with an argument, I call a function with it. It works.
But if I add another instruction below, the backquoted instruction is not executed.

Here is the dummy example:

```el
(setq words '())

(defun func-test (name)
  "Function test."
  (message "Function called with %s" name)
  (add-to-list 'words name))

(defmacro macro-test (name)
  "Macro test."
  (message "Before ...")
  (unless (member name words)
    `(func-test ,name))
  ;;;; /!\ Bug: if I uncomment this next line, it does not work anymore
  ;;(message "... After")
  )

(macro-test 'hello)
(message "%S" words)
;; Should be (hello)

(macro-test 'thanks)
(message "%S" words)
;; Should be (thanks hello)

(macro-test 'bye)
(message "%S" words)
;; Should be (bye thanks hello)
```

Do you have any idea or tip to deal with it?

Bonus question: can I use several backquoted instructions in this macro or is there a specific form to use it? E.g. if I want to call several functions from my macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably aware that macros get evaluated at macro-expansion-time which isn't the same as run-time (that's why you are not just using a function in the first place). When a macro is "first evaluated" at macro-expansion-time it returns a form which later gets evaluated at runtime.

In your `macro-test` macro the last form is `(message "... After")`. At macro-expansion-time it is evaluated which results in `"... After"` being shown in the echo area (which you shouldn't do except for debugging purposes) *and* the same string being returned - first by the `message` form, and then because that is the last form in the macro body, also by the macro being expanded. That string then becomes the macro expansion. Evaluating a string has no side-effect, so nothing happens.

The form which is supposed to be evaluated at run-time has to be the last form in the macros body. Think of the macro as a function which just happens to be evaluated at some other time. If you want a function to return a value then you have to make sure that the last form in its body actually returns that value - it's exactly the same with macros.

---

To make a macro which expands to calls to several functions just return a form which does that, e.g.

```
(defmacro foo (arg)
  `(progn (bar ,arg)
          (baz)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear and instructive (as in "well explained") answer. it totally makes sense ... now that you told it this way :)